# What is the singularity of a bathtub whirl?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, singularities, vortex

I have read that at the center of a bathtub whirl the velocity should be infinite and that is a singularity.

Could someone explain this and the mechanism that viscosity counteracts this infinite velocity?

Comment: Where did You read that? There is a big difference between a Rankine whirl and a real whirl.

Comment: What difference?